# Kafka POM dependency version Issue

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka stream 2.3.0 dependency in my project, but when I am building JAR along with 2.3.0 I am seeing 2.0.1 Kafka version and causing Kafka connection issues.
I never use 2.0.1 in my code, Want to know from where Kafka taking this version

```
<properties>
    <streams.version>2.3.0</streams.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>${streams.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In pom.xml i am using 2.3.0 Kafka version but I am seeing both 2.3.0 and 2.0.1 Kafka version in  "Effective POM" file

Comment: run mvn dependency:treeto see where this dependency is coming from

Comment: I run mvn dependency:tree and seeing 2.3.0 version only.
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:2.3.0:compile

Comment: Is there any way in changing properties in the "Effective POM" file?

Comment: That's weird: if it's not in the dependency tree, it should not be in the Effective POM (at least not as a dependency). Please provide a minimal example to reproduce that.

Comment: In our POM I hardcoded the Kafka version to 2.3.0 and still, it's downloading both the dependencies.I check the whole code i never used 2.0.1 version in our code.

Comment: can you share your pom file please

Answer (score 0):

Apache kafka might be addded as a transitive dependency:

Please specify specific version of kafka for your requirement in pom.xml. refer below:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka

Also optionally you can exclude dependency that you dont want:

```
   <properties>
    <streams.version>2.3.0</streams.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
    <version>${streams.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
          <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 

  </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried by Kafka's specific version(2.3.0), but still facing the same issue.

Comment: you can exclude dependency as referred

Comment: then it will select one you provided explicitly

Comment: exclude dependency works for me, Any idea why is Kafka acting like that?

Comment: `kafka_2.12` is a test dependency, not a compile one https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.3.1